# How to Get Array values in a Separate Variabales

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am using ajax and get a response in json format but i have no idea how to separate each array format in a single variable
i am getting this 
Response

```
final_string =     [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":2,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":1,"q3":1,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":1,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":1,"q11":0},
    {"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":5,"q1":17,"q2":17,"q3":17,"q4":17,"q5":17,"q6":17,"q7":17,"q8":17,"q9":17,"q10":17,"q11":17}  ]

    [ {"feedback":"Ambience"},
    {"feedback":"Efficiency of Service"},
    {"feedback":"Friendly and Attentive"},
    {"feedback":"Variety in Menu"},
    {"feedback":"Presentation of Food \u0026 Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Food"},
    {"feedback":"Anticipated your needs Prior to Asking"},
    {"feedback":"Value for Money"},
    {"feedback":"We made you feel like a Valued Guest"},
    {"feedback":"Would you Recommend us to Others"}  ]
```

i just want to make it like

```
variable1 =  [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":2,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":1,"q3":1,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":1,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":1,"q11":0},
    {"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":5,"q1":17,"q2":17,"q3":17,"q4":17,"q5":17,"q6":17,"q7":17,"q8":17,"q9":17,"q10":17,"q11":17}  ]

variable2 =  [ {"feedback":"Ambience"},
    {"feedback":"Efficiency of Service"},
    {"feedback":"Friendly and Attentive"},
    {"feedback":"Variety in Menu"},
    {"feedback":"Presentation of Food \u0026 Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Food"},
    {"feedback":"Anticipated your needs Prior to Asking"},
    {"feedback":"Value for Money"},
    {"feedback":"We made you feel like a Valued Guest"},
    {"feedback":"Would you Recommend us to Others"}  ]
```

Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FeedBackGraph.aspx/getFeedBackdata",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Response) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log("Response",Response);
                    var d = Response.d; // Response
                    },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
```

i have no idea how to separate each in a variable using JavaScript/jquery?

Comment: `final_string =     [{"` is not defining a string, `[` before any other delimiters indicates an array... sounds like the API you're trying to use is broken, better to fix that instead

Comment: If that really is the response you're getting, it's invalid JSON: `Error: Parse error on line 5:
...7,"q11":17}  ]    [ {"feedback":"Ambie
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '['`

Comment: `var v1 = data.filter( x => x.hasOwnProperty('stars')); var v2 = data.filter(x => x.hasOwnProperty('feedback'))`

Comment: You need to return a valid JSON

Comment: @kiranvj Actually this json format is output of (marge) two diff response

Comment: @kiranvj How to merge two diff table data in a single response of ajax and how to separate that also

Comment: @aparnarai how are you merging it? and why you need to merge responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you need this.

```
    var final_string =    [ [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":2,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":1,"q3":1,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":1,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":1,"q11":0},
    {"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":5,"q1":17,"q2":17,"q3":17,"q4":17,"q5":17,"q6":17,"q7":17,"q8":17,"q9":17,"q10":17,"q11":17}  ],

    [ {"feedback":"Ambience"},
    {"feedback":"Efficiency of Service"},
    {"feedback":"Friendly and Attentive"},
    {"feedback":"Variety in Menu"},
    {"feedback":"Presentation of Food \u0026 Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Food"},
    {"feedback":"Anticipated your needs Prior to Asking"},
    {"feedback":"Value for Money"},
    {"feedback":"We made you feel like a Valued Guest"},
    {"feedback":"Would you Recommend us to Others"}  ]]
var pp=Object.assign({}, final_string)
var z=Object.keys(pp)
var constVar="variable";
var newObj={};
for(var i=0;i<z.length;i++)
{
    var key=constVar+z[i];
    newObj[key]=pp[z[i]];
}
```

[image]

Comment: how to fix it in a two diff variables

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you fix your invalid JSON problem, then ES6 would allow for using a **destructuring assignment**:

```
const [variable1, variable2] = final_string
```

```js
final_string = [
  [{
      "stars": 1,
      "q1": 0,
      "q2": 0,
      "q3": 0,
      "q4": 0,
      "q5": 0,
      "q6": 0,
      "q7": 0,
      "q8": 0,
      "q9": 0,
      "q10": 0,
      "q11": 0
    },
    {
      "stars": 2,
      "q1": 0,
      "q2": 0,
      "q3": 0,
      "q4": 0,
      "q5": 0,
      "q6": 0,
      "q7": 0,
      "q8": 0,
      "q9": 0,
      "q10": 0,
      "q11": 0
    },
    {
      "stars": 3,
      "q1": 1,
      "q2": 1,
      "q3": 1,
      "q4": 1,
      "q5": 1,
      "q6": 1,
      "q7": 1,
      "q8": 1,
      "q9": 1,
      "q10": 1,
      "q11": 0
    },
    {
      "stars": 4,
      "q1": 0,
      "q2": 0,
      "q3": 0,
      "q4": 0,
      "q5": 0,
      "q6": 0,
      "q7": 0,
      "q8": 0,
      "q9": 0,
      "q10": 0,
      "q11": 0
    },
    {
      "stars": 5,
      "q1": 17,
      "q2": 17,
      "q3": 17,
      "q4": 17,
      "q5": 17,
      "q6": 17,
      "q7": 17,
      "q8": 17,
      "q9": 17,
      "q10": 17,
      "q11": 17
    }
  ],

  [{
      "feedback": "Ambience"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Efficiency of Service"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Friendly and Attentive"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Variety in Menu"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Presentation of Food \u0026 Beverages"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Quality and Taste of Beverages"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Quality and Taste of Food"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Anticipated your needs Prior to Asking"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Value for Money"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "We made you feel like a Valued Guest"
    },
    {
      "feedback": "Would you Recommend us to Others"
    }
  ]
]

const [variable1, variable2] = final_string

console.log(variable1)
console.log(variable2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting data correctly, but its not a valid json. The JSON should be like this,

```
[   

  [put your star array here],
  [put your feedback array here]

]
```

so the final response code will be something like

```
[
  [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":2,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":1,"q3":1,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":1,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":1,"q11":0},
    {"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
    {"stars":5,"q1":17,"q2":17,"q3":17,"q4":17,"q5":17,"q6":17, "q7":17,"q8":17,"q9":17, "q10":17,"q11":17}  ],


[ {"feedback":"Ambience"},
    {"feedback":"Efficiency of Service"},
    {"feedback":"Friendly and Attentive"},
    {"feedback":"Variety in Menu"},
    {"feedback":"Presentation of Food \u0026 Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Beverages"},
    {"feedback":"Quality and Taste of Food"},
    {"feedback":"Anticipated your needs Prior to Asking"},
    {"feedback":"Value for Money"},
    {"feedback":"We made you feel like a Valued Guest"},
    {"feedback":"Would you Recommend us to Others"}  ]

]
```

You need to do the above in backend. Remove `final_string =` from response, you don't need that.

And in your success handler you can do something like this to get stars and feedback array.

```
var variable1 = Response[0];
var variable2 = Response[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **destruction** of es6

```
const [variable1, variable2] = final_string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = final_string.match(/\[(\r\n|\r|\n|.)+?\]/g).map(s => JSON.parse(s))
const variable1 = data[0]
const variable2 = data[1]
```

This could be work, but not good.

```
const final_string_1 = "[[...],[...]]" 
const final_string_2 = "[...], [...]"
```

This format maybe more good for parse.